# Javascript ignore case

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

quick question here. Im writing a discord bot in discord.js, which uses javascript. Here is a snippet of my current code:

`if (message.content.includes("hello")){
            message.react("")}`

This, however, only returns the react if it is in that exact case, not if it is Hello, HELLO or helLO. How could i change the code so it accepts all variations?

Many thanks for any answers

Comment: `if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes` or `/hello/i.test(message.content)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance many thanks, i will try this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You to can convert one side or both into lower or uppercase and then compare.

```
var message = "Hello World";
if(message.toLowerCase().includes("hello".toLowerCase()){
 message.react("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use following snippet to find case insensitive matches.

```js
let message = "Okay google Chrome say Hello";
let regex = new RegExp("hello","gi");

if(message.match(regex)){
  //react
   console.log("Reacting");
}else{
  console.log("Not reacting");
}
```